# div width changing function

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone tell me why the function does not accept  the first value if I want to change the div  from input  in real time. Also, the function does not activate the reducing the input value ec  400px to100px. Works well  from entering second parameter. If enter 244, div  change only to 44px. If entering space after that it go to 244 which is correct. But it is not UX correct. Need only javascript solution for this.
Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>gr</title>
    <style>#in{
 border:1px solid grey;
 height: 200px;
 width: 100%;
 transition: all 1s;
     }
     </style>
</head>
<body>

   <div id='in'></div>
    <input  type="text" id='sisse' onkeypress="change()">
 <script>
     function change(){
      document.getElementById('in').style.width=document.getElementById('sisse').value+'px'
     }
   
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `onkeyup` instead of `onkeypress`

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `onkeypress` to `onkeyup`

> The onkeypress event is not fired for all keys (e.g. ALT, CTRL, SHIFT, ESC, BACKSPAC ...) in all browsers. To detect only whether the user has pressed a key, use onkeydown or keyip instead, because it works for all keys.
>
> The keypress event is fired when a key is pressed down and that key normally produces a character value

```js
function change(){
      document.getElementById('in').style.width=document.getElementById('sisse').value+'px'
     }
```

```css
#in{
 border:1px solid grey;
 height: 200px;
 width: 100%;
 transition: all 1s;
 }
```

```html
<div id='in'></div>
<input  type="text" id='sisse' onkeyup="change()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `onchange` event.
Inside the function parameters you can pass the element that's firing the event, in this case, it will be the input, so you can do this:

```
<input  type="text" id='sisse' onchange="change(this)">
<script>
     function change(el) {
         document.getElementById('in').style.width=el.value+'px'
     }
</script>
```

The reason because you should not use `onkeypress` is because this event fires before the input is updated, so when reading the input value you will not get the updated one. Instead, `onchanges` fires everytime that the input is updated.

Comment: Actually, the reason is that onkeypress just takes inputs that produces a character value. The workflow is `keydown` first, then `keypress` and finally `keyup`. `keydown` and `keyup` takes keycode but `keypress` only charcodes